# How to find double integral borders knowing the object's limitations?

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a task:

> Find the volume of bodies bounded by the following surfaces $z=1+x+y$, $z=0$, $x+y=1$, $x=0$, $y=0$.

The figure looks like this but without top left part:
[image]
I know that at first, I have to write double integral of z: $\iint_V{}^{}(1+x+y)dxdy$
Then I have to get an integral like this: $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}(1+x+y)dxdy$ but I don't understand what numbers should I put instead of $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of the region in  XY plane is given by $x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y \leq 1$ (see the below diagram).

[image]

So the integral to find the volume is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} (1 + x + y) ~ dx ~ dy = \frac 56$

OR

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (1 + x + y) ~ dy ~ dx$